# Вычислить x по итерационной формуле C#

Tags: c#, классы, методы

Условие задачи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мои попытки реализовать задуманное, но код явно работает неправильно:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double x, // значение x
           y, // значение y
           prevy,// предыдущее значение y, y0 по условию
           ch = 10, // число, возводимое в степень
           st = -5; // степень по условию

    Console.Write("Введите значение X: ");
    x = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    prevy = x;

    do
    {
        y = (prevy + x / prevy)/2;
        prevy = y;
    } while (!((y - prevy) < 2 * Math.Pow(ch, st)));
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(y);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Нужно, чтобы в цикле do while он сначала проверял условие, а потом присваивал prevy = y.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычислить значение x по итерационной формуле C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749477/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-x-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b5-c)

Comment: В чем отличие этого вопроса от [вашего предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749477/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-x-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5-c)?

Comment: Случай другой, проще в исполнении

Comment: То есть, по сути, отличие только в формуле?

Comment: По сути - да, только в формуле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересно, чему равно `(y - prevy)` в условии `while`?

```
        prevy = y;
    } while (!((y - prevy) < 2 * Math.Pow(ch, st)));
```

Вот так:

```
    y = x;
    do
    {
        prevy = y;
        y = (prevy + x / prevy)/2;
    } while (Math.Abs(y - prevy) >= 2 * Math.Pow(ch, st));
```

Answer (score 4):

Окей, допустим у нас есть некоторая формула. Не важно какая, для этого вопроса или предыдущего вопроса от того же автора

```
public double Formula(double yi, double x)
{
    return (yi + x / yi) / 2;
}
```

Можно написать код, который будет вычислять 2 значения по этой формуле и сравнивать с погрешностью

```
public double Calculate(double x, double epsilon)
{
    var yprev = x;
    var ynext = Formula(yprev, x);
    while(Math.Abs(ynext - yprev) > epsilon)
    {
        yprev = ynext;
        ynext = Formula(yprev, x);
    }
    return ynext;
}
```

Прошу заметить, что в своем коде автор забыл, что меньше погрешности должна быть не разность 2 значений, а модуль разности, так как разность может быть и отрицательной. 
Ну и как запустить:

```
Console.WriteLine(Calculate(4, 10e-5));
```

UPD. Внесу некоторые пояснения.

Итак, что требуется сделать автору вопроса? Ему требутся вычислять последовательно Yi = F(Yi-1, X) до тех пор, пока не выполнится |Yi - Yi-1| < EPS

Где,

F(Y, x) - Функция для получения следующего значения Yi

Yi - значение некой функции на итерации i

Yi-1 - значение той жефункции на итерации i-1

EPS - погрешность вычисления

Таким образом, формально алгоритм для i-ой итерации должен выглядеть так:

1. Вычисляем Yi
2. Вычисляем |Yi - Yi-1| - разницы между текущим значением и предыдущим
3. Если разница из п.2 меньше, чем погрешность EPS, то алгоритм закончен, возвращаем Yi как результат
4. Если раница из п.2 больше или равна погрешности EPS, то идем на следующую итерацию алгоритма

В случае ТС:

Функция F(Y,x) = (Y+ X / Y) / 2; (в моем коде это метод Formula)

EPS = 2*10e-5 - погрешность вычислений

Comment: Не могли бы вы немного пояснить вашу запись? Что такое epsilon и как один метод работает с другим?

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил немного описания алгоритма